# Android install multiple apps as system apps

Tags: android, mobile, apk, android-install-apk

Is there any tool to install multiple apps(4 apps) as a system apps on android rooted device directly.

I done it using **ES File Explorer**  but the problem is, how to install those apps as system apps in more devices (1000 or 10000 devices) quickly.

Is there any tool to do that kind of situation.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution,
Connect device to PC using USB cable and enable **USB debugging**
Creating  **.bat** file with these commands.
Save bat file where .apk file located and double click .bat file and execute.

> adb remount
>   adb push apk-filename-here /system/app/
>   adb shell chmod 644 /system/app/apk-filename-here
>   adb reboot